# cant insert data to just one of my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, insert

I am developing website and the funny thing is that I can insert data to all table except one of my table.

**PHP PART**

```
function newproperty(){
    global $link;
    if(isset($_POST['sendprop']) && $_POST['agree'] == 'Yes'){
        $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
        $owner=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['owner']);
        $tel=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['tel']);
        $email=$_SESSION['cust_user'];
        $type=$_POST['type'];
        $loc=$_POST['location'];
        $address=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['address']);
        $bed=$_POST['bed'];
        $price=$_POST['price'];
        $descrip=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['desc']);     
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
        $thumb = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], 'assets/propthumb/'.$thumb); 
        $query="insert into property 
                (prop_name, prop_email, prop_owner, 
                 prop_tel, prop_type, prop_location, 
                 prop_bed, prop_price, prop_thumb, 
                 prop_desc, prop_address) 
                values 
                  ('$name','$email','$owner',
                   '$tel','$type','$loc',
                   '$bed','$price','$thumb',
                   '$descrip','$address')";
        $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if($run){
            echo"<script>alert('Property has been inserted successfully');</script>";
            echo"<script>window.open('list.php','_self');</script>";
        }
   }
}
```

**HTML PART**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="container bgsearch shadow">
    <div class="container-fluid ">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <img src="assets/images/hero1.png" class=" img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h3 class="wtxt text-center">Submit Property</h3>
                <br>
                <hr id="hr">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                <a href="list.php" class="form-control btn btn-success btn-block">List of my properties</a>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control btn-block" name="name" placeholder="Property Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control btn-block" name="owner" placeholder="Owner Name">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control btn-block" name="tel" placeholder="Owner Telephone Number">
                <select class=" btn-block form-control" name="type" required>
                    <option value='...'>...</option>
                </select>
                <select class=" btn-block form-control" name="location" required>
                    <option value='...'>...</option>
                     .

                </select>
                <input type="text" class="form-control btn-block" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                <input type="number" name="bed" class=" btn-block form-control" placeholder="Bedroom" min="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="number" name="price" class=" btn-block form-control" placeholder="Price (TL)" step="25" min="200">
                <lable class="wtxt"><h5><b>Property Thumbnail Image</b></h5></lable>    
                <input type="file" class="form-control btn-block" name="pic" accept="image/*">
                <textarea class="form-control btn-block" name="desc" rows="6" required></textarea>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="Yes"> Agree With Terms &amp; Conditions 
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-warning btn-block" name="sendprop" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<?php newproperty(); ?>
```

What I have tried and still does not work are:
1. Drop table and make new one
2. change name of my table
3. change insert into... values to insert into.. set...
4. ....

Please help me as soon as you can.

Comment: What happens currently when you try to insert? Error message? Also why are you only escaping some of the values?

Comment: also this `if($run){...}` doesn't always tell the real truth. Use `mysqli_affected_rows()`. Add `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()` including error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Do you get any errors returned, either from PHP or from MySQLi?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And no, the few fields you're manually escaping are **NOT** enough to prevent this. what makes you think email addresses can't have sql metacharacters in them?

Comment: *"What I have tried and still does not work are: 1. Drop table and make new one 2. change name of my table 3. change insert into... values to insert into.. set... 4. ...."* - what does this have to do with what you posted?

Comment: thanks guys for fast reply I tried to put else for if ($run) conditon. when I inset data i just get else condition which i provide by simple echo.

Comment: and I do not get any error at all.

Comment: Try by changing this if(isset($_POST['agree']) && $_POST['agree'] == 'Yes')

Comment: Please add the value of `$query` to your question; could be helpful.

Comment: [**How to debug small programs** http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)

Comment: **HTML PART** - is that file `.php` extension? if not, that won't work if it's `.html` since you have a PHP directive in it `<?php newproperty(); ?>` - unless you instruct Apache to treat your file as PHP. Too many unknowns at this point now and if session was started or that your column types are correct and the right lengths.

Comment: Last suggestion/ditch effort. Make a new file with one or two inputs, using the same table and make sure the column types are correct and the column lengths are long enough to hold the data; MySQL may be failing silently. Once you've gotten that to work, then add more inputs as you go. If you're using JS that you're not showing us, then that could be a factor. You should also escape all data. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried with one input and it does not work :D

Answer (score 0):

Handle an error condition, e.g.

```
    if($run){
        // whatever
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('SQL error: " 
           . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($link))
           . "');</script>"
    }
```

As to figuring out why the statement isn't working, for debugging, emit the SQL text and test that in a different client.

---

You're calling `mysqli_real_escape_string` function on some values, but not on others. So, your SQL `INSERT` statement is still vulnerable to SQL Injection.

A better pattern is to use a **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**. It's really not that hard.

Comment: I personally like to use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) in conjunction with error checking. It's a *truer* true ;-)

Comment: I tried your echo statement but does not shom me even the alert panel

Comment: *Hm...* wondering if the session's even been started. `$email=$_SESSION['cust_user'];`

Comment: yes fred I echo all of them and it shows me. there is no problem in posting data. the problem is that data does not insert to table

Comment: check your column types and lengths @MOSH and make sure you chose the right database and table. We don't know where `$link` is defined as or which DB you're using. I am out of this loop now, good luck. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php too

Comment: What happens if you run the query in the db directly? Does MySQL throws any error?

Comment: @Fred-ii- tanx for your help but the rest of the form in this application works great and as i mention first just this table does not work. anyway tanx again

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes you can insert data manually without any error